# Execute multiple MySQL statement at once in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently, my code works if it has only one statement:

```
$stm = $conn->prepare("insert into my_table(a, b) values(?, ?)");
$stm->bind_param("ii", $a, $b);
```

Now I want to execute multiple statements at once to avoid round-trips.

```
$stm = $conn->prepare("delete my_table where a = ?; 
                      insert into my_table(a, b) values(?, ?)");
$stm->bind_param("iii", $a, $a, $b);
```

The code above doesn't work though.

Comment: Check that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632902/mysqli-can-it-prepare-multiple-queries-in-one-statement and also a work around but without `prepare` in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `mysqli` library.

You are missing the execute bit

i.e. read http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I think he omitted intentionally the `execute` command. But either way you can not `prepare` a multi-query with a single `prepare` statement.