# Generate multiple query string and execute one by one

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mysql.`my_autoinc` (
    `table_schema` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `table_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `auto_increment` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`table_schema`, `table_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Query 1:**
List of all tables named `table1` or `table2` in any DB.

```
REPLACE INTO mysql.`my_autoinc`
SELECT table_schema, table_name, NULL AS `auto_increment`
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name IN ("table1", "table2");
```

*Query 1* may generate

```
table_schema  |  table_name  |  auto_increment
===============================================
 client_1     | table1       |    NULL
 client_1     | table2       |    NULL
 client_2     | table1       |    NULL
 client_3     | table1       |    NULL
```

**Query 2:**
List of query string.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'REPLACE INTO my_autoinc ',
    'SELECT "',table_schema,'", "',table_name,'", MAX(Id) FROM ', 
    '('
        'SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id FROM ', table_schema, '.', table_name,
        ' UNION ',
        'SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id FROM ', table_schema, '_history.', table_name, '_history',
    ') t'
) AS 'queries'
FROM my_autoinc;
```

When the list of query generated by the *Query 2* was executed.

```
table_schema  |  table_name  |  auto_increment
===============================================
 client_1     | table1       |    99
 client_1     | table2       |    60
 client_2     | table1       |    299
 client_3     | table1       |    399
```

**I already tried:** `GROUP_CONCAT` but the concatenated length of the string is more than 1000. So, can't execute a query of that length.

**Update:** I can't do [multiple statements in a prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11635064/1753174).

**Solution Required:** To execute queries generated by *Query 2* one by one.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the max lenght from GROUP_CONCAT

```
-- for the session
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

-- or global
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Comment: But, I can't prepare multiple statement. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11635064/1753174

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a stored procedure like this and then call it:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE doAllThings()
BEGIN
  DECLARE cursor_VAL VARCHAR(2000);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR
    SELECT CONCAT('REPLACE INTO mysql.my_autoinc ','SELECT "',table_schema,'", "',TABLE_NAME,'", MAX(Id) FROM ', '(SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id FROM ', table_schema, '.',TABLE_NAME,' UNION ','SELECT MAX(Id) AS Id FROM ', table_schema, '_history.', TABLE_NAME, '_history',') t') AS 'queries' FROM mysql.my_autoinc;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_VAL;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET @SQL := queries;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;     

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


-- call it
call doAllThings();
```