# Insert and Update in different table in one process

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert-update

I've created a form containing an input field which has an autocomplete function and the other input field was set as readonly.

```
<div id="windowContent">
        <form action="rdpw_monitoring_process.php" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="10px">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="padding-left:5px;" name="auto_username_rdpw" id="auto_username_rdpw" class="auto_username_rdpw" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Default Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="nccc2016" class="form-control" name="default_password_rdpw" id="default_password_rdpw" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <br />
        <div style="padding-right:100px; float:right;"><input type="submit" name="reset" value="RESET" id="reset" class="reset btn btn-info" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

When I put a username and click the submit button it will automatically update the Table 1 (tbl_userlist) of some fields then it will insert the userid from Table 1 (tbl_userlist) that was base on the updated fields. My update query was working but my insert query was not working. Is it possible to combine an insert and update query in different table in one process just like my process code below?

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');

    $autocomplete_username = $_POST['auto_username_rdpw'];
    $default_password = $_POST['default_password_rdpw'];

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=etransmittal', 'root', '');

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_expiration_ninety_days = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+90 days"));

    $update_qry = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = :default_password, lastdate_changepw = :date_change_password, password_expiration = :password_date_expiration WHERE username = :username");

    $insert_qry = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_reset_change_expire_password (userid, lastdate_resetpw)
                                VALUES ((SELECT userid FROM tbl_userlist WHERE lastdate_changepw = :change_password_date LIMIT 1), $current_date)");

    if($update_qry->execute(array(':default_password' => $default_password, ':date_change_password' => $current_date, ':password_date_expiration' => $date_expiration_ninety_days, ':username' => $autocomplete_username))){
        echo "You have successfully edit into default password";
    }
    else{
        echo 'Failed to reset default password.';
    }

    $insert_qry->execute(array(':change_password_date' => $current_date));
?>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "combine an insert and update query in different table in one process just like my process code below"? You mean you want to do one SQL query that does an insert and an update at once? (Because you want them to be atomic? Or because you just want to do one query to the database?)

Comment: Um, It's possible @pvegetah

Comment: This may help [multiple statement in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632902/mysqli-can-it-prepare-multiple-queries-in-one-statement)

Comment: @jbafford, my problem is my insert query was not working. And I'm just asking Sir if it is possible to implement my logic on this process.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code may be work properly........

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');

    $autocomplete_username = $_POST['auto_username_rdpw'];
    $default_password = $_POST['default_password_rdpw'];

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=etransmittal', 'root', '');

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $date_expiration_ninety_days = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+90 days"));

    $update_qry = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_userlist SET user_password = :default_password, lastdate_changepw = :date_change_password, password_expiration = :password_date_expiration WHERE username = :username");

    $insert_qry = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_reset_change_expire_password (userid, lastdate_resetpw)
                                VALUES ((SELECT userid FROM tbl_userlist WHERE lastdate_changepw = :change_password_date LIMIT 1), :change_password_date)");

    if($update_qry->execute(array(':default_password' => $default_password, ':date_change_password' => $current_date, ':password_date_expiration' => $date_expiration_ninety_days, ':username' => $autocomplete_username))){
        echo "You have successfully edit into default password";
    }
    else{
        echo 'Failed to reset default password.';
    }

    $insert_qry->execute(array(':change_password_date' => $current_date));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to perform an `INSERT` to one table and an `UPDATE` to another table in the same SQL statement.

It might be possible to achieve what you want using a trigger (e.g. `AFTER UPDATE ON` the table you are updating, which can perform an `INSERT`. But you can't pass in an argument to a trigger. The values have to be available from the row you are updating, or from a user-defined variable.

---

But that doesn't really seem to be the problem. It seems like what you really want is a transaction, and you only want to perform the `INSERT` if the `UPDATE` is successful.

It also seems that you'd want the `INSERT` to be based on the `username` of the row that was updated, not the last updated date/time.

In your example code, it seems like you'd want an INSERT statement more like this, assuming `username` is unique in `tbl_reset_change_expire_password:

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_reset_change_expire_password (userid, lastdate_resetpw)
 SELECT l.userid, :change_password_date 
   FROM tbl_userlist l
  WHERE l.username = :username
```

If you wanted to do that in a trigger, then you could get the `userid` value from the row you updated. But the datetime would need to come from somewhere, like the database server via the `NOW()` function. (The timezone would be dependent on the setting of the MySQL session variable.)

In the body of an `AFTER UPDATE ON tbl_userlist` trigger, you could perform an INSERT like this...

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_reset_change_expire_password (userid, lastdate_resetpw)
 SELECT NEW.userid, NOW()
```

But that's two separate statements that are executed, but you'd only need to execute the `UPDATE` from the code. The INSERT would be performed "behind the scenes" as it were, via the trigger.