# inserting to multiple tabels and giving same id's in both table

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to insert to multiple table using single registration form in android. and want it to insert same id's to both tables but it's taking different id's, can someone tell me what should i do for this?

DbOperations.php

```js
public function createUser($name, $surname, $username, $user_pass, $address, $pin, $mail, $phone, $a, $b, $c, $d){
   if($this->isUserExist($username,$mail,$phone)){
     return 0;
   }else{
    $password = md5($user_pass);
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_data` (`name`, `surname`, `username`, `password`, `address`, `pin`, `mail`, `phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmt->bind_Param("ssssssss",$name,$surname,$username,$password,$address,$pin,$mail,$phone);
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
     return 2;
    }
    $stmtcate = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `employee_category` (`name`, `pin`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $stmtcate->bind_Param("ssssss",$name,$pin,$a,$b,$c,$d);
    if ($stmtcate->execute()){
     return 1;
    }else{
     return 2;
    }
    
   }
  }
```

Comment: Which API do you use? PDO or mysqli?

Comment: Check for error Messages and Show it here.

Comment: @Jens mysqli.. and i am checking it usning postman.

Comment: is it possible to use multiple statements mysqli->prepare? No. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632902/mysqli-can-it-prepare-multiple-queries-in-one-statement

Comment: @Jens in login function i've used it adding UNION method. so i thought it would work.

Comment: Union is one Statement, `;` separated Statements are two

Comment: @Jens i got it, but not completely... like what to do for bind_param and execute for another $stmt?

Comment: @jens... can you reply?

Comment: Sorry can not get you

Comment: @Jens I've updated my question please check it once

Comment: You do not bind the values to the second statement

Comment: @Jens thanks mate... You helped me. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept it

Comment: @Jens why did you deleted your answer? it's working but only not taking the same id's

Comment: Because the answer is not completly right

Comment: @Jens yeah! that's true but we are just near to it. anyways let me know if you find any answer... i am searching the web for it too...

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute two Statements in one call of execute, so you have to split it into two Statements:

```
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_data` (`name`, `surname`, `username`, `password`, `address`, `pin`, `mail`, `phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_Param("ssssssss",$name,$surname,$username,$password,$address,$pin,$mail,$phone);
            if(!$stmt->execute()){
                return 2;
            }
            $stmt1 = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `employee_category` (`pid`,`name`, `pin`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); ");
            $stmt1->bind_Param("issssss",$stmt->insert_id(),$name,$pin,$a,$b,$c,$d);
            if($stmt1->execute()){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 2;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but i just not did it myself... :) only problem is... it's taking different id's in both tables which is auto incremental how to keep the id's same in both my table for the same user.?

Comment: @SumitPal see my updated answer. It is the solution for mysqli. Hope this is the API you are using

Comment: @SumitPal BTW, you should not use the technical ID (autoincrement) as foreign key for both tables.

Comment: it's not working bro... it's showing {"error":false,"message":"User register successfully"} but inserting only to `user_data`

Comment: getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::mysqli_insert_id() in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 32 my line 32 is "$stmtcate->bind_Param("issssss",$stmt->mysqli_insert_id(),$name,$pin,$a,$b,$c,$d);"

Comment: @SumitPal Have changed my answer again. But id can not be an autoincremant in the second table

Comment: I've updated my CreateUser function but is still not working... only taking insert values to 'user_data' but not to 'employee_category' and showing this error: " Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_Param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 32" check my updated DbOperations.php in my question.

Comment: Then you have an SQL error in your second SQL statement

Comment: but before adding this $stmt->insert_id() it was working fine and was taking values to both tables. without any error. can you please check my updated DbOperations.php content one more time?

Comment: Maybe your column Name is not `id`?

Comment: Hey Bro, I've already done it... please check my DbOperations.php which in in my question section.

Comment: @SumitPal Please never write "not working". explain what is not working and which error message do you get

Comment: okay, after adding "$stmt->insert_id()" it's inserting data to only user_data table but another tables isn't taking any values and showing this error: "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::insert_id() in C:\wamp64\www\Android\include\DbOperations.php on line 32" check image to see detailed error [https://www.dropbox.com/s/3h8s2wv6byijiyi/Untitled3.png?dl=0]

Comment: did you find any solution?