# mysqli_stmt_close() expects to be parameter 1

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been coding in `PHP` and connecting it up to `MySql`. I keep on getting an error

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_stmt`, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx on line 175

Is there anything wrong with this block of code?

```
 if(empty(trim($_POST['dept'])) && empty(trim($_POST['fname'])) && empty(trim($_POST['lname'])) && empty(trim($_POST['email'])) && empty(trim($_POST['cnum'])) && empty(trim($_POST['dob'])) && empty(trim($_POST['gender'])) && empty(trim($_POST['minitial'])) && strlen(trim($_POST['minitial'])) > 1   ){
            $regerr = "Please complete your information";
        }else{
            $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
            $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
            $email = trim($_POST['email']);
            $cnum = trim($_POST['cnum']);
            $dob = trim($_POST['dob']);
            $gender = trim($_POST['gender']);
            $dept = trim($_POST['dept']);
            $minitial = trim($_POST['minitial']);
        }

        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($usernameerr) && empty($passworderr) && empty($confirmpassworderr) && empty($regerr) ){

            // Prepare an insert statement
            $sql = "INSERT INTO login_info (username, password) VALUES (?, ?);
                    INSERT INTO user_info (fname, sname, minitial, contact_num, gender, dob, department) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,CAST (? AS DATE),?);";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_fname, $param_sname, $param_minitial, $param_cnum, $param_gender, $param_dob, $param_department);

                // Set parameters
                $param_username = $username;
                $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
                $param_fname = $fname;
                $param_sname = $lname;
                $param_minitial =$minitial;
                $param_cnum = $cnum;
                $param_gender = $gender;
                $param_dob = $dob;
                $param_department = $dept;

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['usernumber'] = $mysqli_insert_id($link);
                    header("location: home-trabawho.php");
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php

Comment: Your `prepare` will fail as it doesn't work with multiple SQL statements (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632902/mysqli-can-it-prepare-multiple-queries-in-one-statement), your close should be within the `if` statement of the `prepare` working.

Comment: Put the `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` inside the `if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){` block.

Comment: Or check if the statement is not false/empty with `if($stmt) mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO login_info (username, password) VALUES (?, ?);
                INSERT INTO user_info (fname, sname, minitial, contact_num, gender, dob, department) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,CAST (? AS DATE),?);";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
```

There is not **one** insert statement, as the comment pretends, there are **two** statements.

The documentation of [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) clearly explains:

> ```
>  mysqli_stmt mysqli_prepare ( mysqli $link , string $query )
> ```
>
> Prepares the SQL query, and returns a statement handle to be used for further operations on the statement. *The query must consist of a single SQL statement.*

Accordingly, `$stmt` is `false`, the `if` branch is not executed and

```
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

correctly fails.

You should put the call to `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt)` inside the `if` block, in the first place. And you should check the value returned by `mysqli_prepare()` and handle the errors accordingly.

In this specific situation you should use two pairs of `mysqli_prepare()`/`mysqli_stmt_execute()` statements to run the two `INSERT` queries. In the `user_info` table you probably also need to insert the ID generated by the first `INSERT` query, to link the two records inserted by these queries.