# PHP) mysqli_prepare doesn't work in if statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make an english vocabulary app. Reactjs and php is used in this app and currently I have problem with preventing SQL injections.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
in this link I found I can do

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','databasename');
if($stmt= mysqli_prepare($conn, SQL QUERY)){}
```

to make a prepared statement, my code is almost same as the example, but just SQL is different

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/');
$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$contentJSON = json_decode($content);
$addEnglish = $contentJSON->english;
$addKorean = $contentJSON->korean;
$addSwedish = $contentJSON->swedish;
$addSynonyms = $contentJSON->synonyms;
$addExample = $contentJSON->example;
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]+/', $addEnglish)&&!preg_match('/\s/', $addEnglish))
{
include 'db/db_connection.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','worddb');

if(connectDB($conn)){
    if($mysqliPrepare=mysqli_prepare($conn,
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDLIST(
            wordIndex INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
            english VARCHAR(20),
            korean VARCHAR(20),
            swedish VARCHAR(20),
            synonyms TEXT,
            example VARCHAR(100),
            UNIQUE KEY wordDBIndex (wordIndex)
        );
        INSERT INTO WORDLIST (english, korean, swedish, synonyms, example)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"
    )){
        echo "prepared ".$mysqliPrepare;
        mysqli_smt_bind_param($mysqliPrepare,"s",$addEnglish,$addKorean,$addSwedish,$addSynonyms,$addExample);
        mysqli_smt_execute($mysqliPrepare);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($mysqliPrepare, $district);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($mysqliPrepare);
        mysqli_stmt_close($mysqliPrepare);
    }
    print_r("</br>error ".mysqli_stmt_error($mysqliPrepare));
    print_r("</br>error ".mysqli_stmt_error($conn));
    print_r("</br>error ".$mysqliPrepare);
}
}else{
echo "search again";
}
```

connectDB function is from db_connection.php

```
<?php 
function connectDB($conn){
    $connectStatus = null;
    if (!$conn) {
        $connectStatus = false;
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        echo "Connected successfully";
        $connectStatus = true;
    }
    return $connectStatus;
}
?>
```

I tried SQL query in phpmyadmin and it worked there, but in php script it seems like SQL query or mysqli_prepare function is buggy because inside if statement is just never triggered. I mean I don't see message "prepared" which php should show. The table doesn't want to be created too.

That's why I did some mysqli_stmt_error to see what error do I get, but
[image]

I get such errors, so I cannot even get mysql error message.. it seems like

```
if($mysqliPrepare=mysqli_prepare($conn,
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDLIST(
        wordIndex INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
        english VARCHAR(20),
        korean VARCHAR(20),
        swedish VARCHAR(20),
        synonyms TEXT,
        example VARCHAR(100),
        UNIQUE KEY wordDBIndex (wordIndex)
    );
    INSERT INTO WORDLIST (english, korean, swedish, synonyms, example)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"
))
```

problem is inside in this code but I can't see any problem with it because same SQL code works perfectly in phpmyadmin.
I even tried '?' instead ? but doesn't work.

Comment: you should create table separately because every time you want to run this code, you will get error because you are trying to create the same table every time. I suggest you to create a different configuration file to setup schema initially. Remove the create table line for now and test the insert query only.

Comment: You don't need to create the table every time, you can just set it up already in mysql when you install your application

Comment: @ADyson I know, but I am doing this to learn MYSQL :D

Comment: When you looked up the mysqli_prepare() statement at php.net you must have missed statement: "Prepares the SQL query, and returns a statement handle to be used for further operations on the statement. The query must consist of a single SQL statement."

Comment: And also the misspelled  mysqli_smt_ lines in your code need fixing. If you do separate the statements, as others have already advised and helping you to learn, it does work.

Comment: You need to stop manually checking for errors. Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439) and [Should I manually check for errors when calling “mysqli_stmt_prepare”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62216426/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can combine two queries in the same statement (create + insert). Try splitting them up.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632902/mysqli-can-it-prepare-multiple-queries-in-one-statement

Comment: Aha ok thanks... didn't know that mysqli_prepare cannot handle multiple queries.. awful :(