# Add to string in mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm wondering if there's a way to add something to a mysql column (some form of string) in a specific row, or if this is even an issue at all with the way the server handles requests.

For example:

Each thread would have a row in a database, with comments being a column within the row, featured as a JSON array.

The function to add a comment would be ordered something like this

- get Current Comment JSON
- decode the json, and add the new comment to it
- re-parse to JSON, and insert back into the database

However, this brings up the issue of this:

User 1 sends request to server to post a comment on a thread

User 2 sends request to post another comment on the same thread

- User 1's request > loads current JSON
- User 2's request > loads current JSON
- User 1's request > adds the comment to its data, updates the database
- User 2's request > adds the comment to its data, updates the database, removing User 1's comment entirely

is this even a problem? if so, what would be the steps needed to prevent this?

Comment: This is what transactions are for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: Have a little read at database transactions, good example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli

Comment: Comments really should be their own table. You could also solve this by doing it as a CONCAT, set the column = column+new text.

Comment: I'm with what @Jessica said in her first sentence. (Then I'm not there after that :>)

Comment: @Jessica is right 100%... then you don't have to worry at all about the data being overwritten.

Comment: @DrewPierce I don't like my second sentence much either, TBH. ;)