# How to insert data in multiple tables mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am trying to insert data from a form in 2 separate tables which are linked by clientID, however I am getting an error:

> INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', 'a a', 'a', 'a', 'a');INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '1', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '2015-08-28', '2015-08-31', '3', '4', 'Extra Remarks');
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights' at line 1

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

    $apartment = (isset($_POST['apartment']) ? $_POST['apartment'] : null);
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $surname = (isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : null);
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $mobile = (isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : null);
    $pax = (isset($_POST['pax']) ? $_POST['pax'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $remarks = (isset($_POST['remarks']) ? $_POST['remarks'] : null);
    $day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
    $month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
    $year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
    $month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
    $year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$name $surname', '$email', '$address', '$mobile');";
    $sql.= "INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$days', '$pax', '$remarks');";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "";
            } else {
                echo "" . $sql . "<br>" .mysqli_error($conn);
  }
  ?>
```

GOAL SQL:

> BEGIN;
>   INSERT INTO client_detalis (clientID, name, email, address, mobile)
>     VALUES('', '$name $surname', '$email', '$address', '$mobile');
>   INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, remarks, pax)) 
>     VALUES('', $apartment, LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$nights', '$pax', '$remarks');
>   COMMIT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

```
<?php

    $apartment = (isset($_POST['apartment']) ? $_POST['apartment'] : null);
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $surname = (isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : null);
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $mobile = (isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : null);
    $pax = (isset($_POST['pax']) ? $_POST['pax'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $remarks = (isset($_POST['remarks']) ? $_POST['remarks'] : null);
    $day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
    $month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
    $year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
    $month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
    $year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

  include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$name $surname', '$email', '$address', '$mobile')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$days', '$pax', '$remarks')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
// important to insert as code will not work without commit
 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mysqli transaction methods, like described in this answer:
[how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli)

Comment: If the tables are already created, is it ideal to recreate them?

Comment: @Christa No you haven't the link is only an example, you can ignore the "create table" and "drop table" statements.

Comment: Tried the suggestion but for some reason the table is not updating.  Even though I don't have errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have not errors? Add echo mysqli_error($conn); before closing the connection.

Comment: Yes I am, as I checked with the " printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);" and got not errors.  However I think I have figured out the solution.  I had forgotten to commit.

Comment: posted my solution.  :)