# Transaction is not working - PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm beginner to PHP transaction concept. My code is not working. I don't know what is my mistake. Anyone help me to find out my mistake.

My first query is wrong one. It didn't work. Second is successfully executed. If I have checked by IF condition, My control successfully moved to else part. It's fine. But My rollback function not working. Second query date will be present in table.

What is my mistake?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hrms_db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

/* Transaction start */
mysqli_begin_transaction($link, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

/* disable autocommit */
mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);

$result1  = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO EmployeeBackup (Name, OfficialEmail, Department, Manager_ID, MobileNO, Status, Location, full_name) value ('s', 's', '1' , '3', '5', '4', '5' , '78')");
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO hrms_general_master (lookup_type,   lookup_description) value ('Testing', 'Testing')" );

if($result1 && $result2){
/* commit insert */
mysqli_commit($link);
echo "All queries were executed successfully";
} else{
/* Rollback */
mysqli_rollback($link);
echo "All queries were rolled back";
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Then please explain different type of parameter used in `mysqli_begin_transaction` and use of it. I have little more doubt in `mysqli_begin_transaction` and `mysqli_commit`. Please clarify my doubt.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli may be helpful

Comment: Wow. thanks. I have wrongly set my search engine. Now I changed to InnoDB. Now it is working. But I have gotten one more doubt. Why transaction is working only in InnoDB.?

Comment: ya thanks subin thomas. I want to know flow of program execution. I read out more article. But still I have doubt on it. Please share some more details among the flow of transaction.

Comment: That's how mysql was created, only supports transactions for InnoDB, other engines may be faster but lack this very important functionality.

Comment: ya thanks xception..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the InnoDB access method to use transactions. The people who created MyISAM did not include transactions in their code.

Plenty of tutorials on the net explain DBMS transactions in general, and MySQL transactions in particular. Here is just one.
 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-transactions.htm

Comment: Thanks Ollie jones!! I changed my access method into InnoDB. Now it is working fine. Once again thanks a lot. But still I am having little more doubt regarding this transaction concept. Please share some more details related to transaction. Jones.!