# How does the mysqli execute function work internally?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a DB where I have some tables, most of them irrelevant for this question:

Content_handler:

```
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| app_data_id | app_menu_entry_id | content_item_container_id |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| 0           | 0                 | NULL                      |
| 0           | 1                 | bm9zb3Ryb3MtMC0w          |
+-------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

App_menu_entry:

```
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| app_menu_entry_id | position | name    | icon_id      |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
| 0                 | 0        | Nombre  | asd          |
| 1                 | 1        | Precios | icontest.png |
+-------------------+----------+---------+--------------+
```

Content_item_container:

```
+---------------------------+--------------+
| content_item_container_id | content_name |
+---------------------------+--------------+
| bm9zb3Ryb3MtMC0w          | Nosotros     |
+---------------------------+--------------+
```

`content_handler.app_menu_entry_id REFERENCES TO app_menu_entry.app_menu_entry_id`

`content_handler.content_item_container_id REFERENCES TO content_item_container.content_item_container_id`

Now, when I want to update app_menu_entry I DELETE all records from this table (with cascade, so also deletes content from content_handler) and then I insert data with PHP from an array so I use a foreach with prepared statements like this:

```
$menuQuery = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO app_menu_entry(app_menu_entry_id,position,name,icon_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$handlerQuery = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO content_handler(app_data_id, app_menu_entry_id, content_item_container_id) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$id = 0;

if (!$menuQuery || !$handlerQuery) {
    ErrorHandler::setError(ErrorHandler::DB_QUERY_ERROR, true);
    throw new \Exception('Error al realizar la consulta');
}

foreach ($menu['menu_items'] as $menuItem) {
    $name = $menuItem['name'];
    $position = $menuItem['position'];
    $icon = $menuItem['icon_id'];
    $contentId = ($menuItem['content'] != null) ? base64_encode($menuItem['content'] . '-' . $userId . '-' . $appId) : null;

    $menuQuery->bind_param('ssss', $id, $position, $name, $icon);
    $menuQuery->execute();

    $handlerQuery->bind_param('sss', $appId, $id, $contentId);
    $handlerQuery->execute();

    $id++;
}
```

The problem is that this loop insert data in app_menu_entry but not in content_handler. This can be solved adding `sleep(1000);` between `execute()` function and that make me think how can I prevent using `sleep()` and how this execute function works? Does it uses a thread, makes a async queue...?

Comment: I guess you need transaction  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli

Comment: ->execute() should block and not return until the execution has completed. that being said, you're simply assuming the queries are succeeding. unless you enabled exceptions, the db calls will simply return boolean false on failure, which you never check for it. if there's some kind of sync problem, you'll never know.

Comment: The second execute sentence works fine ( I tried it outside the loop with static values to test errors but nothing found)

Comment: Yep, $id increments inside the loop.

Comment: At the risk of asking another dumb question, where does @appId come from? (Since it is involved in the assignment of $contentId, which is used to reference another table.)

Comment: $appId = '0'; always.

Comment: Is `app_menu_entry.app_menu_entry_id` an auto-increment field?

Comment: Nop, the field is a normal varchar(255)

Comment: just look at the source code for this if you need to know the internals