# How to transaction MySQLi OOP

Tags: php, transactions

Trying to make a transaction, so only if all the queries will succeed, they are executed. I did a lot of them in procedural, but first time in OOP style. I've seen [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples), and [How to start and end transaction in mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli), no result.

So I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this two queries:

```
$connection->autocommit(FALSE);
$connection->query("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('1')");
$connection->query("INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('a')");
if($connection->commit()){
    echo "Commit";
} else {
    echo "Rollback";
}
```

As bar is INT, the first query will succeed, and the second fail. But although I am using a transaction and the second query fails, the first one is executed, and I don't understand why.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `bar int(11)` So it demands an integer...

Comment: @PraveenKumar question is not about what it demands.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about why the transaction commits when the second query if failing. I am doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: @Nanook Please read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: @Praveeen Kumar, but that's exactly what I am doing. I can't find any difference…

Comment: In fact, I just copied the example in php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php , and same result.