# How to set mysqli error if any of 4 mysql query fails

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my database project there is a form where the user will fill in to add more data to the stock. I have 4 tables in my database. During the submit of the form the if the user fills in a primary key that is already there there will have a `mysqli_error()`and it will state that the user has entered invalid data. But currently my lines of code has an order (please ignore that the values are not in english)

The lines below are to insert data into my first table and if there is a error it would come out as an error

```
$datastok = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT into stok (Kod_Barang, Kod_Rak, Harga, Tarikh_Jual) VALUES ('$Kod_Barang','$Kod_Rak','$Harga','$Tarikh_Jual')")or die(mysqli_error());
```

The lines below are to insert data into my second table and if there is a error it would come out as an error

```
$databarang = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT into barang (Kod_Barang, Nama_Barang, Bil_Barang) VALUES ('$Kod_Barang','$Nama_Barang','$Bil_Barang')")or die(mysqli_error());
```

The lines below are to insert data into my third table and if there is a error it would come out as an error

```
$datalokasi = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT into lokasi (Kod_Rak, Jenis_Barang) VALUES ('$Kod_Rak', '$Jenis_Barang')")or die(mysqli_error());
```

The lines below are to insert data into my forth table and if there is a error it would come out as an error

```
$datatarikh = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT into tarikh (Nama_Barang, Tarikh_Beli) VALUES ('$Nama_Barang', '$Tarikh_Beli')")or die(mysqli_error());
```

I am trying to make it so if any of the `mysqli_query()` fails all of it wont insert.

example of whats happening now:

`$datastok` runs perfectly

`$databarang` also runs perfectly

`$datalokasi` has an error and the `mysqli_error()` will stop it here and `$datatarikh` wont run .

So in this situation i would like that all `$datastok $databarang $datatarikh` will not execute if `$datalokasi` fails.

Comment: Try to use mysql transactions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: The thing you need is a Transaction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the START TRANSACTION / COMMIT

first start with

```
mysqli_query($connection,"START TRANSACTION;");
```

and then run all your quesries **without** the **or die()**

after all queries run, check if there are any errors in one of them,

if there are no erros then COMMIT

```
mysqli_query($connection,"COMMIT;");
```

if there are errors so ROLLBACK

```
mysqli_query($connection,"ROLLBACK;");
```