# MySQLi deletes savepoints (and only savepoints) upon transaction error?

Tags: php, mysqli, savepoints

I'm finding myself a bit confused by the way MySQLi handles savepoints when encountering an erroneous query.

Here's an MRE of the problem I'm having:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($_HOST, $_USER, $_PASS, $_DB_NAME); // replace with credentials
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$mysqli->savepoint("SP1"); // savepoint() method - I get the same problem when using the SAVEPOINT query
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Users (Username, FavouriteColour) VALUES ('Alice', 'Red');"); // valid query
$mysqli->savepoint("SP2");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Users (Username, FavouriteColour) VALUES ('Bob', 'Green');"); // another valid query
$mysqli->savepoint("SP3");
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Users (Username, FavouriteColour) VALUES ('Charlie', 'Blue');"); // third valid query
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE Users (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Username VARCHAR(255), FavouriteColour VARCHAR(64));"); // obviously invalid query - Users already exists.
$mysqli->query("ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT SP2"); // Time to rollback! I use the ROLLBACK query since the rollback($name) method doesn't actually rollback to the savepoint with the name parameter.
$mysqli->commit(); // Commit the transaction.
```

After this small transaction, the last two adds should have been rolled back, right? That's definitely what happens when there *isn't* an invalid query in the middle of the transaction. Alice should be added, but Bob and Charlie shouldn't.

The presence of a (not syntactically, but logically) invalid query in the middle of the transaction apparently seems to throw MySQLi off completely. Instead of either keeping the transaction and letting me roll back to when I feel like it, or undoing the entire transaction (which would be understandable since there's been an error in there), MySQLi keeps the whole transaction *but deletes all the savepoints*. When I try to rollback to any of the three savepoints above, it gives me a "savepoint does not exist" error. As a result, all three valid queries are committed (even if I don't manually commit them at the end, and even if I try to roll back the last two, as above).

Unless I'm doing something wrong here, MySQLi is deciding that the best way to deal with an error is to keep executing all the queries but getting rid of all the savepoints (which are...how you deal with errors). Please let me know if either myself or MySQLi is being stupid here!

Note - when there is no invalid query in the transaction, the savepoint / rollback works perfectly well. The first query gets executed, then the second and the third, but the rollback to SP2 cancel the second and third queries, so only the first is committed.

Comment: Is this a problem only with mysqli? What is the behaviour when you do it directly in MySQL CLI or some other client like MySQL workbench?

Comment: "*obviously invalid query - Users already exists.*" This would throw an error in PHP, wouldn't it? You aren't handling the error anywhere.

Comment: Also, I believe that the thing about the query being valid or invalid is a total red herring here.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error in PHP: you can throw as many invalid queries as you want at MySQLi. It logs the error, and obviously in my actual code I handle it (by rolling back, which doesn't work!), but here I've omitted that for the purposes of this question. Maybe you're right about the query being valid or invalid, but the fact is that when I comment the "create table users" query out, the savepoint / rollback works perfectly.... I'm really not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: mysqli is PHP., It does have a setting to silence the errors, but I don't think that's what we are talking about here.

Comment: Sorry - I'm unclear - invalid SQL queries do throw an error (by logging it into the mysqli::error property), but not fatally - they don't crash the programme, invalidate the transaction, or prevent me in any way from continuing to execute more SQL queries. The handling of the mysqli::error is precisely why I need the rollback system to work!

Comment: Then you must have forgotten to enable exception with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. Please don't forget this. And please update to a more recent version of PHP.

Comment: Thank you v much for answer below, that's exactly it (would upvote if I could)! I've been manually disabling the exceptions (MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF) and dealing with them at the surface level rather than as exceptions (allowing me to ROLLBACK any error queries) - going from your comment that's clearly not good practice, is manual error handling dangerous?

Comment: @BrianSmooner it's generally regarded as obsolete. You can still use `try/catch` to handle individual exceptions if you wish. But in a lot of cases that's unnecessary and so it's generally more graceful and less code-intensive to let other mysqli exceptions be handled by PHP itself, and logged etc according to the way your application already handles other exceptions. See https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#error_handling and then https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting for a good guide to dealing with such errors in mysqli and then across your whole php app.

Comment: Please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli/63764001#63764001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are implicitly committed by DDL statements. A `SAVEPOINT` is part of a transaction. When a transaction is committed, the savepoints are deleted.

> All savepoints of the current transaction are deleted if you execute a COMMIT, or a ROLLBACK that does not name a savepoint.

The transaction is committed before the DDL statement is attempted. Therefore, it's irrelevant whether the `CREATE TABLE` query succeeds or fails. The savepoints will be removed either way.